# How to diagnose this client-side script module resolution issue

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I am having an issue while trying to use a library, this has happened many times before with other libraries so I decided to ask a question that will give me some techniques to troubleshoot issues like this.

Case in point is a javascript caching library called [cached](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cached). I added this to `package.json`, and started using it in my `angular` application created using `ng-cli`. In my app.component.ts I have.

```
import { cached } from "cached";
```

Once I added the line above, `ng-serve` recompiled and reloaded the browser and I started seeing the following errors in Chrome console.

[image: Chrome console]

`ng-serve` shows the following messages in the console

> ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
>
> Date: 2019-12-18T17:05:27.385Z Hash: d0dc919769ccdbb75bf5 Time:
>   12785ms chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 12 kB [initial]
>   [rendered] chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map
>   (polyfills) 241 kB [initial] [rendered] chunk {runtime} runtime.js,
>   runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.22 kB [entry] [rendered] chunk {styles}
>   styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 15.6 kB [initial] [rendered] chunk
>   {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.85 MB [initial]
>   [rendered]
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/memcached/lib/connection.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in
>   'C:\dev\temp\angular\cachetest\node_modules\memcached\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/hashring/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'crypto' in
>   'C:\dev\temp\angular\cachetest\node_modules\hashring' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/memcached/lib/utils.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'crypto' in
>   'C:\dev\temp\angular\cachetest\node_modules\memcached\lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/memcached/lib/memcached.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'net' in
>   'C:\dev\temp\angular\cachetest\node_modules\memcached\lib' i ｢wdm｣:
>   Failed to compile.

What is wrong with this library? Am I not using it correctly? What process did you or should I have used to find what is wrong?

Comment: Try npm install. This should install all dependencies of the library you are using as well.

Comment: Any error after `ng serve` in command line? it must have something that would help you to resolve the issue.

Comment: The github repository is named `node-cached`. With such a name, you can safely assume that this library is a NodeJS library, intended to be run in NodeJS, not in the browser, where Angular apps execute.

Comment: @PankajParkar I am sorry I missed the `ng-serve` logs. I have updated my question.

Comment: @vcode I did with no luck

Comment: @JBNizet It looks like you are correct. Their github page's title states that too. You can post this as an answer.